# iOS form sheet keyboard does not disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitextview

I know that I have to call

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
//this dismiss keyboard on ios
- (BOOL) textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self.comments resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

In order to dismiss keyboard on a form sheet, I also know that I have to call `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` in the navigation controller if I have one.

Problem is: I create forms sheet with navigation controller programmatically like:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
SettingsViewController *settingsVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settingsViewController"];
//add navigation controller 
UINavigationController *modalViewNavController= [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsVC];
modalViewNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
modalViewNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:modalViewNavController animated:YES];
```

So I don't have a navigation controller class for form sheet, how can I dismiss keyboard in this case?

Do I have to create a navigation view controller?

**UPDATE:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::**

End Up creating a navigation controller in the storyboard and call `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` in the navigation controller's view controller, that solved the problem but I still wonder how to do this without creating a navigation controller class.

Any input is welcomed......

Comment: please can you tell me how did you implemented the disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal in the view controller?

Comment: @user2176995 if your forms sheets root is navigation controller you have to put `- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}` in `navigation controller's .m` file otherwise just put the code in your `viewcontrollers.m` file

Comment: Will it work if I created a subclass of a uiNavigationController, added the method to it, and then set the subclass in the storyboard for the navigation controller as the custom navigation controller class? As after implementing the method, I hide the keyboard by real sing first responder is that right ?

Comment: thats correct. you need to call ` resignFirstResponder` in your form sheets controller though

Comment: i tried it and it didn't work :(

Comment: I cant say anything without seeing your code, create a question in `stackoverflow` with details so people can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try the following code;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)hideKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me:

```
@interface UINavigationController (dismissKeyBoard)

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (dismissKeyBoard)

- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```