# Dismiss Keyboard presented in modal View Controller (Form sheet)

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, modal-dialog

I have a modal View Controller, presented as Form Sheet on the iPad.
When I send [textField resignFirstResponder], the Keyboard remains on the screen.

In the View Controller:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

In the Navigation Controller:

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}
```

All this worked using iOS 6, but not with iOS 7.

Comment: Please refer to my answer here which works fine:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23195187/527539

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following method to the actual ViewController (rather than the NavigationController) worked for me in iOS 7.

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}
```

I'm calling a method that is hooked to the Text Field's Sent Event Editing Did End.

```
- (IBAction)KeyboardDoneKeyPressed:(id)sender
{
   [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Prior to adding the method disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal the keyboard would not dismiss when pressing Done.